# How to disable automatic URL parameter decoding in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, routes, urlencode

I have a `viewset` with a `retrieve` view, which takes one parameter, which is a string url encoded, as it often has '/' in it. Now when I send a request to my local development server with the url encoded (every `/` replaced by `%2F`) I get a 404 from my server and in the "Request URL" I see my string but decoded - so it makes sense that there is no such route. The route shows up correctly in this debug view with `api/ ^topic/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$`. This is my viewset:

```py
class TopicAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        if '%2F' in pk:
            pk = pk.replace('%2F', '/')
        # Data retrival which works (independently tested)
        return Response(topics)
```

I tried different words and different replacement methods, i.e. '--' instead of '2%F' which works but isn't nearly as stable as url encoding.